# How to fix formik.getFieldProps is not a function error when using Field and useFormikContext in different components?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How to fix `formik.getFieldProps` is not a function error when using `Field` and `useFormikContext` in different components?

I am using Formik to create various form components in React. Some of them use the `<Field>` component, while one of them uses the `useFormikContext()` hook. These components are imported from different files into separate form components (wrapped with `<Formik>`). However, when I try to render the components that use `<Field>`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: formik.getFieldProps is not a function
```

I also see this warning in the console:

```
Warning: Formik context is undefined, please verify you are calling useFormikContext() as child of a <Formik> component.
```

I have tried two solutions, but none of them worked:

1. Replacing `<Field>` with `useFormikContext()` in the components that
   use it.
2. Replacing `useFormikContext()` with `<Field>` in the component that
   uses it.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this error?